# Universal Image Loader: Share Intent Null Pointer

Tags: android, image, android-viewpager, share, universal-image-loader

I've implemented a share button in my ImagePagerActivity.java however It doesn't attach the image because of  a null pointer when I try to share, the image is not attached. PLEASE HELP.

```
    ishare= (Button) findViewById(R.id.share);
    ishare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(final View view) {

      ...

            //Create new Intent to send image
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            //Set Intent Type
            intent.setType("image/png");
            //Create URI for image link
            int index = pager.getCurrentItem();
            assert imageUrls != null;
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(imageUrls[index]);
            //Set Intent extra with URI created from image link
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
            //Start new activity to share image
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share image with"));


        }

    });
```

Comment: Please share logcat result and also make sure `imageUrls` Array or `pager` is not null before accessing values or methods

Comment: And Uri object should be valid local `Uri`. It probably begins with `content://`

Comment: it doesn't generate an error but it doesn't attach the image that's suppose to be shared

Comment: The issue I reckon is in this line "Uri uri = Uri.parse(imageUrls[index]);"

Comment: DONT WORRY. I GOT IT WORKING

Comment: @user3135837 Would you mind posting your solution? I have run into the same exact problem.